# Anything.DomainName.com redirect to DomainName.com/xx/test.html using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect WildChar.DomainName.com to DomainName.com/xx/test.html using .htaccess

.htaccess code is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\.DomainName\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xx/index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

***[update] I am unable to post to superuser.com for some reason, so please do not close / move this question there***

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 0):

You might try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domainname\.com
RewriteRule .* http://domainname.com/xx/index.html [R]
```

The condition should match any non-empty subdomain.

If you want to pass the information about which subdomain was accessed to the redirected site, then you can add %1 (which is the first regex match from the RewriteCond) to the redirect, e.g.

```
RewriteRule .* http://domainname.com/xx/index.html?from_subdomain=%1 [R]
```

Comment: If the subdomain is empty or it is a wildcard then?

Comment: The '(.+)' matches any non-empty string, so it's a wildcard. If no subdomain is given, then the Condition/Rule does not match.

Comment: The rule does an external redirect, so the new URL should be visible in the browser address bar. If it is http://domainname.com/xx/index.html then the rule works as intended. (Do you really want to redirect to `/xx/index.html` or should `xx` be replaced with the subdomain?)

Comment: sub=domain can be anything, but it should be redirected to /xx/index.html

Comment: I tried the configuration above myself and could not find any problems. Could you please check the URL that causes the 404 error and specify if the problem is either that a) the redirect does not work at all or b) you are redirected to the wrong URL.

Comment: Oops! Google Chrome could not find xx.DomainName.com.  There must be something amiss here.  Its not redirecting at all, but it says there is no sub-domain called xx.